# Installing GHCi requires to change my path to use in terminal

Tags: haskell, installation, terminal

[![I'm trying to write Haskell code in a text editor then run it with GHCi in my terminal. I successfully installed GHCi (I think), and am trying to run a command to run some code I wrote, but I there is no command found for ghci or ghc. Do I need to change my terminal path to where I downloaded/installed GHCI? Also if I change the path will it permanently change my starting path in terminal? Here's the last thing my terminal says. I've also tried stack ghci.

EDIT

My error is that the commands are not found when I run them in terminal.
I installed everything by running this command in my terminal and continuing to type YES when prompted.

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh`

The contents of /Users/Jack/.ghcup/env is

`export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:/Users/Jack/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Are you able to provide the contents of `/Users/Jack/.ghcup/env`? What command did you run to install HLS?

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual error message text instead of an image of it.

Comment: @ShaneBishop, I posted a picture of the contents of the folder

Comment: @dfeuer, my error message is that the commands are not found, whether I type ghci or stack ghci.

Comment: @JackB, please delete both images and replace them with text. Images are not accessible or searchable and in this context they do not add value.

Comment: I was asking for the contents of the `/Users/Jack/.ghcup/env` *file*, not the contents of the *folder*. Also, please see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for an explanation of how to include output from your terminal in properly formatted text instead of using images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note to others reading this**: I recommended `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc` because I know from the original question (before it was revised) that the OP is using a Mac ([more info on bash on Macs](https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-bashrc.html)).

---

Try running these three commands in order in your terminal:

```sh
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:/Users/Jack/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
. ~/.profile
ghci
```

What this will do is modify your [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) as necessary so that your shell can find the `ghci` program. It will also store this modification in your `~/.profile` so your `PATH` will have the correct value next time you log in.

> Also if I change the path will it permanently change my starting path in terminal?

The `PATH` environment variable is not related to the initial working directory of your terminal. So no, your terminal's "starting path" will not be changed.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that the first two commands are one-time-only. Terminals opened after running them should Just Work when you type `ghci` alone.

Answer (score -1):

Just write `. ~/.ghcup/env` in the `~/.zshrc` file. Another thing is restarting the terminal.